# Backup Sharepoint 2013 site using powershell or stsadm

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, backup

I am trying to take backup of of my sharepoint 2013 site `http://something1:6060/` using powershell or stsadm but getting some errors.

Using Powershell
command:`Backup-SPSite "http://something1:6060/" -Path "C:\site.bak"`

> error: you must specify the filename of the backup file

Using stsadm
command:`stsadm -o backup -url "http://something1:6060/" -filename "c:\backup.bck"`

> error: One or more required arguments are missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Powershell, try skipping the quotes around the site URL:

```
Backup-SPSite http://something1:6060/ -Path "C:\site.bak"
```

The same goes for stsadm

Comment: What is the reverse of this? How would you do a restore?

Comment: As you almost said in your comment, you Restore the backup: Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak .More here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx

Comment: similar to the  site collection backup, can we take the backup of content db too using the PowerShell? if i dont want to go with  SSMS client?

Comment: @SaMolPP Have you tried to google it? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428327.aspx was the first hit

Comment: @RobertLindgren , am looking for a content db backup and not the complete farm backup.  Here is the link from where, i  have taken the code: http://sqlmag.com/powershell/powershell-lets-you-back-sql-server-your-way . but it throws import-module error

Comment: Backup-SqlDatabase : The 'Backup-SqlDatabase' command was found in the module 'SQLPS', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SQLPS'.
At line:19 char:1
+ Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $svnm -Database $dbname -BackupFile $bfil
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Backup-SqlDatabase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

Comment: The `Backup-SPFarm` has an `-Item` parameter where you can put the name of the database, it is described in the link I provided you. It would probably help you to read the information provided @SaMolPP

Comment: @RobertLindgren , my idea is to take the back up of the content db from my current farm and restore/mount it to my second farm, so that I can replicate the same UI/operations/functionality in my new second farm. so i thought of taking the content db ONLY and not the entire farm backup.Also I have some 20+ content dbs in my first farm.So thought of writing a PowerShell which automates this! It would  be useful for me post Go-Live as well.!

Comment: Again, the command helps you to backup a single database

Comment: Will `Backup-SPSite` work with subsites too?